# How to create a unknown length numpy array and increase the size according to the given number

Tags: arrays, python-2.7, numpy

I have to initialize an array of unknown length and the increase the size dynamically. I did this with normal python arrays and tried to do with numpy arrays.But I didn't find a way to initialize an unknown length array and increase the array according to the user given input. Below given are the codes that I tried with normal python arrays.

ImageIdList.py

```
    class arr(list):
        def __setitem__(self, id, initialArea):
            if id >= len(self):
                self.extend([None] * (id + 1 - len(self)))
            list.__setitem__(self, id, initialArea)


        def calculateChangeInArea(self,arr,id,newArea):
            if (newArea > arr[id]):
                changedRate = ((float(newArea) - float(arr[id])) / abs(arr[id])) * 100.00
                return changedRate
            elif (newArea < arr[id]):
                changedRate = ((float( arr[id]) - float(newArea)) / abs(arr[id])) * 100.00
                return changedRate
```

areaCalculation.py

```
        class arr(list):
            def __setitem__(self, id, initialArea):
                if id >= len(self):
                    self.extend([None] * (id + 1 - len(self)))
                list.__setitem__(self, id, initialArea)


            def calculateChangeInArea(self,arr,id,newArea):
                if (newArea > arr[id]):
                    changedRate = ((float(newArea) - float(arr[id])) / abs(arr[id])) * 100.00
                    return changedRate
                elif (newArea < arr[id]):
                    changedRate = ((float( arr[id]) - float(newArea)) / abs(arr[id])) * 100.00
                    return changedRate
```

Ann_riskDetection.py

```
from ImageIdList import idList
Id = idList()
from areaCalculation import arr
intialAreaArray = arr()

def riskDetection(imagId,temperature,humidity,sunlight,diseasedSpotArea):
    #This function is called every 2 hours periodically
    #threading.Timer(1440.0, getDiseasedLeafSpot).start()

    if imagId not in Id:
        Id[imagId] = imagId
        intialAreaArray[imagId] = diseasedSpotArea
        changedRate=0.0
        print(intialAreaArray)
        print(Id)
    elif imagId in Id:
        changedRate = intialAreaArray.calculateChangeInArea(intialAreaArray, imagId, diseasedSpotArea)
        print(changedRate)
```

And below given is the code that I tried with numpy arrays.Here I didn't find a way to initialize the unknown array in numpy.

```
import numpy as np

spotsAreaArray=np.zeros(5)
weatherConditions=np.zeros((5,3))

def saveInitialSpotId(spotId,spotArea,humidityReading,temperatureReading,lightReading):
    #Store initial area of the spot at the respective location of the spot id
    if spotsAreaArray[spotId] == 0:
        spotsAreaArray[spotId]=spotArea
        if weatherConditions[spotId].all() == 0:
            sensorReadings=np.array([humidityReading,temperatureReading,lightReading])
            weatherConditions[spotId]=sensorReadings
            print("weather Conditions"+str(weatherConditions))
    print("Spots Area Array :"+str(spotsAreaArray))
```

What I need to know is, I need to run this code in raspberry pi.So If I work with the code that I mentioned above.That means the code I tried with normal python arrays,it will make any errors in raspberry pi. Or can anyone of you guide me to have a numpy array of unknown length, and increase the size according to the user input.(the same logic I used in normal python arrays) Hope anyone of you will kindly address my issue.Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't.  We usually recommend initializing and growing a Python list, and creating a numpy array from that when needed.  You can create an array, and concatenate it with new values, making a new array.  Usually that's less efficient than the list approach.  By the way, a list always has a known length; it just has an efficient `append`.

Comment: Your `arr()` creates an `arr` object (subclass of list) with len 0.  That is 'known'.  A normal list grows with an `append` or `extend`.  You just add the ability to grow `arr` by indexing off the end.  In which case it `extends` with enough `None` entries.

Comment: You can initial an array with 0 elements.  You can concatenate new (empty) elements, but it makes a new array.  There's no inplace grow (except in a limited way with `np.resize`.  And subclassing `ndarray` is a pain.  So I wouldn't try to port the list code to numpy.

Comment: @hpaulj You mean my first method is correct and no need to do it in numpy?

Comment: Numpy also has an `append` function, works just like in lists. Not as efficient as having the size known from the start.

Comment: numpy.append is not just like the list append.  It is poorly named and often misused.

Comment: What's wrong with the list code, if any  thing?  Would a dictionary work just as well?  It's easier to grow.